# How to demonstrate this tautology using equivalences?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

I have this tautology

$(P \wedge (P \rightarrow Q) \wedge (Q \rightarrow R)) \rightarrow R$

I couldnt prove it by using equivalences.

Using Definition of implication and then using negative absoption I have this

P∧(¬P∨Q)∧(¬Q∨R)   // Definition of implication

Using the following equivalence X ∧ (¬X ∨ Y) its equivalent to X ∧ Y

I got

P ∧ Q ∧ R -> R

using again the definition of implication we have

¬(P ∧ Q ∧ R) ∨ r

using the De Morgan rule we have now

¬P ∨ ¬Q ∨ ¬R ∨ R

we know that clearly (¬R ∨ R) is true, so know we have

¬P ∨ ¬Q ∨ True

now with the rule X ∨ True is equivalent to true we know conclude

True

Is a tautology

Comment: What equivalences can you appeal to? It's kinda important. The sentence is just Modus Ponens extended by one more implication, expressed as a formula rather than as a rule of deduction.)

Comment: Your phrase is not a tautology because it does not have the right number of left brackets.

Comment: I can use all equivalences, De Morgan, absorption, asociativity, etc.

Comment: All equivalences include equivalence of each tautology with $\top$, so we only need to use one equivalence.

Comment: I have tried with De Morgan, Absoprtion and Definition of implication but I havent arrieved to true

Comment: How about a truth table?

Comment: I can't use truth table for this exercise

Comment: I've edited the exercise so that it now actually is a tautology. Please check so that it now is the formula which you intended from the start (as you missed a right parentheses originally).

Comment: I think that final closing right bracket should be just before the final `\rightarrow`.

Comment: To notify a user, write "@`username`" somewhere in your comment. And you said you can use all equivalences which is obviously not what you want. Furthermore, if you've tried something, you have to include it in your question, as stated in the rules when you sign up to Math SE.

Comment: @user21820  I have improved the question but still dosent prove that is true

Comment: Did you just copy Josh Chen's answer? Your original phrase is certainly not equivalent to what you wrote.

Comment: @user21820 I used what Josh Chen said and added negative absortion

Comment: No you did not. Show your steps. What you claim it is equivalent to is wrong, and no one can tell you where it is wrong if you don't even show working.

Comment: @user21820 Ok now I give the definition of the equivalence in the question, you can make the truth table and will be equivalent, now using the steps given by Mauro Allegranza I finally arrieved to the solution. Thanks

Comment: Wrong. And you clearly don't know what you're doing. As I said earlier, you claim that you want to prove "(P ∧ Q ∧ R) = True". This is blatantly false.

Comment: @user21820 My bad, I did not explain my self clearly enough I was trying to prove that (P ∧ Q ∧ R) -> R is true not just (P ∧ Q ∧ R). I have changed my question description , with the explanation of the answer

Comment: Okay good your steps are fine. Just make the habit of being more precise, such as at the beginning don't say "I have ..." because it's not true, but rather say "$\def\imp{\rightarrow}$$P \land ( P \imp Q ) \land ( Q \imp R ) \equiv P \land ( \neg P \lor Q ) \land ( \neg Q \lor R ) \equiv \cdots$", and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) $[P∧(P→Q)∧(Q→R)]→R$

2) $[P∧(\lnot P \lor Q)∧(\lnot Q \lor R)] \to R$ --- by [Material Implication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Material_implication_(rule_of_inference))

3) $[(P \land \lnot P) \lor (P \land Q) \land (\lnot Q \lor R)] \to R$ --- by [Distributivity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributive_property#Truth_functional_connectives)

4) $[(P \land Q) \land (\lnot Q \lor R)] \to R$

5) $([(P \land Q) \land \lnot Q] \lor [(P \land Q) \land R]) \to R$

6) $([P \land (Q \land \lnot Q)] \lor [P \land Q \land R]) \to R$

7) $(P \land Q \land R) \to R$

8) $\lnot (P \land Q \land R) \lor R$

9) $(\lnot P \lor \lnot Q \lor \lnot R) \lor R$ --- by De Morgan

10) $\lnot P \lor \lnot Q \lor (\lnot R \lor R)$ --- by Associativity

11) $\lnot P \lor \lnot Q \lor TRUE$

> 12) $TRUE$.

Comment: Thanks, that gived me finally the answer, My mistake was not applying De Morgan to the 3 variables remaining

Answer (score 0):

Recall the equivalence
$$ (P \rightarrow Q) \Leftrightarrow (\neg P \vee Q),$$
write the left hand side
$$ P \wedge (P \rightarrow Q) \wedge (Q \rightarrow R) $$
as
$$ P \wedge (\neg P \vee Q) \wedge (\neg Q \vee R). $$

See what this simplifies to and then see how this means the original statement is a tautology.